# f2py: Pre-allocating arrays as input for Fortran subroutine

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

Here is a minimalized snippet from a Fortran subroutine that i want to call in python. The task is very simple. The first time the code is called a value is assigned to the first entry of the array *iwk*. The subroutine is then called a second time, the expected behaviour would be that the assigned entry is unchanged.

```
subroutine testf2py (md,iwk,ndp,nip)

  implicit none

  integer ndp
!f2py intent(in) :: ndp
  integer nip
!f2py intent(in) :: nip
  integer iwk(31*ndp + nip)
!f2py intent(in) :: iwk     
  integer md
!f2py intent(in) :: md

  if ( md == 1 ) then
    iwk(1) = ndp
  end if  

  print*, iwk(1)

end
```

(first call: *md*=1, subsequent calls: *md*>1). The array *iwk* should be allocated in python and the values in the array should be untouched in between calls. Calling this function in Fortran this works without problem:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: i, ndp, nip  
  integer, allocatable :: iwk(:)

  ndp = 10
  nip = 10

  allocate(iwk(31*ndp+nip))  

  call test (1, iwk, ndp, nip)
  call test (2, iwk, ndp, nip)

end program main
```

Output of the 2 calls:

```
10
10
```

In python, after compiling the subroutine with f2py, it does not work. The values in *iwk* change:

```
import testf2py
import numpy as np

ndp = 10
nip = 10

iwk = np.empty([31*ndp+nip,], dtype=int, order='F')

testf2py.test(1, iwk, ndp, nip)
testf2py.test(2, iwk, ndp, nip)
```

Output of the 2 calls:

```
10
1686728152
```

The second number is random.

I tried allocating in python in different ways, np.empty_like, np.zeros. Did not help. I assumed that the problem lies with how to allocate the iwk array (hence the question title), but not sure. What do i have to change to make it work? Preferably, i want to change only the python script and leave the Fortran code as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tell python that the array is `intent(in)`:

```
  integer iwk(31*ndp + nip)
!f2py intent(in) :: iwk
```

You are not allowed to change it and expect the change will be retained. Probably you want `intent(inout)`.

Even better, forget `!f2py intent` and use directly:

```
  integer, intent(inout) :: iwk(31*ndp + nip)
```

and the compiler will tell you you are wrong if you try to modify an `intent(in)` variable.

Be careful to use the correct `dtype` in Python, it must correspond to the Fortran type. Most often Fortran `integer` is equivalent to `int32`, but it might be `int64` sometimes. You can control that in Fortran too (`integer*4`, `integer(int32)`,...).

Comment: @Vladimir_F thanks for replying. actually i tried this before but it throws me an error (regardless of using f2py intent or direct): ValueError: failed to initialize intent(inout) array -- expected elsize=4 but got 8    any idea?

Comment: What are you initializing it? It probably belongs to a different question. You may try `int32` instead of `int`.